# What is a diff between Cache (Normalized, HTTP) and Persisted queries (Apollo)?

Tags: android, ios, graphql, apollo

An android app uses GraphQL (Apollo), this app has a [Normalized cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/v2/essentials/normalized-cache), in order to reduce the number of queries to the backend.

However, I see there is also [APQ (Automatic Persisted Queries)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/v2/advanced/persisted-queries), as far as I understand it is also a kind of alternative for cache implementation, but on the backend. right?

So, as far as I understand if the app has both `APQ` and `Normalized cache` a query flow looks like this:

`query -> check locally in cache -> if nothing -> send query on server -> if there is nothing in APQ -> execute query and send back to the client -> result saves in APQ -> client receives the response -> save response in normalized cache`

The question is - does it make sense? Doesn't it look like overkill? I mean what is a reason to make an implementation for both `Normalized cache` and `APQ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do different things.  A client side cache reduces queries to the server from your device, eliminating their network traffic and resource usage. A server side cache does nothing for network traffic (you must make a request and return a result), but eliminates the resource usage of the query across multiple devices.  This means if 1000 people need to make a query, the server only needs to execute it once.  The two techniques work together well-  the local cache saves more, but the server side cache is more broadly applicable.